# magento: importing into different stores using magmi

Tags: magento, magmi

I have products that need to be imported into different stores

sku, name, store1, store2, subcat

111, item1, coke, pepsi, subcategory

i wrote out some logic that works for the value replacer plugin:

[{item.store1}]/{item.subcat};;[{item.store2}]/{item.subcat}

the problem is, what if i have some items that only have a value under store1 and are blank for store2 or the opposite?

I get an error when importing that says Cannot find site root with names : ,

Does anyone know of there is a way to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [PHP ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) written in the [Magmi value replacer advanced syntax](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Value_Replacer#Advanced_Syntax_examples) to append the value if the store2 column value exists.

```
[{item.store1}]/{item.subcat}{{(!empty({item.store2}) ? ';;['.{item.store2}.']/'.{item.subcat} : '')}}
```

This basically says if `item.store2` is not empty, then return `;;[{item.store2}]/{item.subcat}`

In actual PHP, this would look more like

```
(!empty($item['store2']) ? ';;['.$item['store2'].']/'.$item['subcat'] : '');
```